# Is it safe to invest $100 Million in Bitcon

Tags: investing

I have currently $300 Million+ in bank account. Do you think is it safe to get returns by investing in Bitcoin considering it has hit Billions in Market Capitalization.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you instead spend some of that on a financial planning expert.